# mapping keypad keys in vim do not respond to control key

Tags: vim, keymapping

I'm using the following mappings to manage the window size:

```
:nnoremap <kPlus> <C-W>+
:nnoremap <kMinus> <C-W>-
:nnoremap <kDivide> <C-W><
:nnoremap <kMultiply> <C-W>>
```

Adding the control prefix to map window jumping does not have any effect:

```
:nnoremap <C-kDivide> <C-W>h
:nnoremap <C-kMultiply> <C-W>l
```

Pressing `<C-kMultiply>` acts the same as `<kMultiply>`

Any idea why?

Comment: Because there is no such `<C-kDivide>` control character?

Comment: Good point. Didn't think of that ;-( On the other hand, why wouldn't there be such a combi?

Comment: Tried to bind control-'keypad x' to an application in XUbuntu. This works, so the control character <C-kDivide> does exist.

Comment: Sometimes it might catch it when considering the control key as an independent "modifier" key. But when talking about terminals, something like `<C-A>` is sent as the character `^A` and probably it doesn't know about any character that suits `<C-kMultiply>`…

Comment: This is a problem with internal representation of input stream (if you are using gvim), it just can’t handle most of `<C-` combos because it can represent only about ASCII control codes. If you are using vim control is cut down before it reaches vim, so it won’t matter whether vim can handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what ZyX said:

Keys like `<C-kMultiply>` will work fine in GVim, which receives keyboard input from the GUI environment, but they are impossible to represent in the stream that serves as terminal Vim's input, due to the venerable way that control characters are defined in it:

> [How control characters map to keyboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#How_control_characters_map_to_keyboards) (Wikipedia)

The control modifier works by simply zeroing two high bits, so that for example <kbd>G</kbd> (​**10**​00111) becomes `BEL` (​**00**​00111). This means that it can only work with single-byte character codes: there's no way to apply it to multi-byte escape sequences such as what `<kMultiply>` actually sends.

(This is also why you can't generally combine <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, in the terminal: both `<C-G>` and `<C-g>` end up as the same control character once the high bits are zeroed.)

What happens in the face of such an unrepresentable key combination varies from terminal to terminal: `xterm`, for example, will ignore the modifier and send `<C-kMultiply>` as `<kMultiply>`, while `gnome-terminal` will refuse to send the keypress altogether.